# Batter run out leaving ground after 1st run

Tags: cricket

A batter hits the ball and runs from the striker’s end to the non-strikers end, he then leaves his ground looking for a second run, stops and tries to return to the non-strikers end but is run out at the non-strikers end. Does the run count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The completed run scores as if the batter had simply stopped running.

Law 18 defines what a run is, and whether they are scored when a dismissal occurs. The relevant parts of law are

> **18.1 A run**
>
> The score shall be reckoned by runs.  A run is scored
>
> **18.1.1** so often as the batter, at any time while the ball is in play, have crossed and made good their ground from end to end.

and

> **18.8 Runs scored when a batter​ is dismissed**
>
> When a batter is dismissed, any runs for penalties awarded to either side shall stand.  No other runs shall be credited to the batting side, except as follows.
>
> ...
>
> **18.8.2** If a batter is dismissed Run out, the batting side shall also score any runs completed before the wicket was put down.